# Android Data Type Recommendation

Tags: android

I'm having a problem designing some code to handle dynamic, two-dimensional data in my Android applicaton.  I've tried solving this using an ArrayAdapter, but there's a problem:

As far as I can tell, there's no way to remove data from an ArrayAdapter by its position (or index).  Using an ArrayAdapter, you have to remove by value like this:

```
arrayAdapter.remove (stringValue1);
```

This is fine for half my data because the first value in the pair (the "x-value") is guaranteed to be unique (among the x'es), but this isn't reliably true for the second value.  I've tried some stupid gymnastics to make the "y-value" unique, but that's not proving to be a very good idea.

Can anyone recommend an Android data type (or Java, I guess) that will be both dynamically re-sizeable and will allow me to remove precisely the data I need to??

Thanks,
R.

Comment: An ArrayList will do what you want

Comment: Working on finding an example right now.  Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ArrayList of String objects, sounds like it would do the job, and it's dynamically resizable as well:

```
ArrayList<String>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Remove by index:

```
remove(int index)
```

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list.

Check if it contains a certain object by object comparison:

```
contains(Object o)
```

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element.